# I can't my access my online database from my android app But it works on localserver

Tags: android, url, android-activity, ip

I need to access my online database by android app. It works on localserver xamp using IP.But not working on online server with ip/url.
Here's the code.

```
   private static final String url_diseases_detials = "http://******.com/c_droid/list_movie.php";
```

also it's not working with IP

```
private static final String url_diseases_detials = "http://192.xxx.xx.x/c_droid/list_movie.php";
```

can please help me. Rest other code are okay.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Please provide some additional details about what you're expecting and what your results are.

Comment: The app is working. But when i click to see the list which are fetched from database then it stopped working.